# inja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected char '!'

Tags: python, jinja2

I'm trying to rendr jinja template, my code is:

```
<span>{{ !!scope.row.is_read ? 'Прочитано' : 'Не прочитано' }}</span>
```

```
env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('app'),
                          comment_start_string="{{{",
                          comment_end_string="}}}",
                          )
        template = env.get_template('html_template.j2')
        return template.render(access_token=security.create_access_token(subject=resp_data['user']['id'],
                                                                         expires_delta=access_token_expires))
```

But I get an error inja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected char '!'.
If I remove !! in html template this error getting on '?'. May i need some extension, can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to put python code inside a tag, which generally you can't do.

Try this:

```
{% if scope.row.is_read %}
<span>Прочитано</span>
{% else %}
<span>Не прочитано</span>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: No, it is js function that gives a value in html tag